# Strategy of uploading video file to Asset (Microsoft Azure Media Service)

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I'm building Angular2 app where user have ability upload video file into Microsoft Azure Media Service via REST API.

If anyone has such experience and can point me in correct way it would be great.

Comment: Please check out this tutorial: [Upload files into a Media Services account using REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-upload-files).

Answer (score 1):

The right solution would be to first upload the file to an Azure Storage container. Once there, you should use the Azure Media Services API/SDK from a back end service (Azure Function or Azure API Management endpoint) to trigger the ingest process. That way you can keep your keys to your AMS account (AAD access via Service Principal account) secure and not leak them to your clients in your Angular javascript code.

In the future (this coming year) we will make this process a lot easier by adding support for ingest directly from HTTP(s) URL or Azure Container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for pure REST API implementation of [Azure Media Services REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-rest-get-started), the project [GaleCrater](https://github.com/Traverous/GaleCrater) does just that. It uses [axios.js](https://github.com/axios/axios) so you can run it with angular from your browser as well though not recommended because your `ClientID` & `ClientSecret` would be leaked.

The thorough strategy is described in the blog post [Starter’s guide to DASH and On-Demand Video Streaming on Azure Media Services](https://medium.com/@Traverous/the-tale-of-how-we-built-on-demand-streaming-for-traverous-on-azure-media-services-87e32f6a98d0).